# swaggerhub and REST API

Tags: node.js, swagger

I use swaggerHub for write the documentation of my new app Node but I have a problem with one api.

My API require two params.
Example : POST http://cloud.amazingwebsite.com/:service/:action

Ok, if you want to use this API, you must to give two values. My problem is that the doc of swaggerHub propose only examples with one param.

Please, do you have a example with two params ? Is it possible ? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--are you asking how to use Swagger?

Answer (score 1):

If you do it like this:

```
  "/{service}/{action}":
    x-swagger-router-controller: serviceController
    post:
      summary: To perform an action
      operationId: serviceAction
      parameters:
      - name: service
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
        description: Request Path Param for service
      - name: action
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
        description: Request Path Param for Action
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/SuccessResponse"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
definitions:
  SuccessResponse:
    type: object
  ErrorResponse:
    required:
    - error
    properties:
      error:
        type: string
```